# Docker on Ubuntu 14.04 my browser is not starting after run command for Kaggle/python

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu-14.04, kaggle

In Kaggle/python docker on Ubuntu 14.04 my browser is not starting.Anyone has face this issue and resolution? I am using below command from terminal

"`(sleep 3 && sensible-browser "http://127.0.0.1:8888")& docker run -v $PWD:/tmp/working -w=/tmp/working -p 8888:8888 --rm -it kaggle/python jupyter notebook --no-browser --ip=0.0.0.0 --notebook-dir=/tmp/working"`

and when I go to Firefox web browser localhost:8888, it ain't show up nothing.

Comment: Please edit your code as formatted text, so that it will be readable

Comment: also try manually launching the browser and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

You can use datmo/kaggle:python to be able to run kaggle projects with jupyter notebook. After pulling the image, you can use code like this in the shell:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8888:8888  -v ~/.:/home/  datmo/kaggle:python 'jupyter notebook'
```

This mounts the local directory onto the container having access to it.

Then, go to the browser and hit https://localhost:8888, and when I open a new kernel it's with Python 3.5. I don't recall doing anything special when pulling the image or setting up Docker.

You can find more information from [here](https://docs.docker.com/v1.10/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/).

You can also try using [datmo](https://datmo.com/) in order to easily setup environment and track machine learning projects to make experiments reproducible. You can run datmo task command as follows for setting up jupyter notebook,

```
datmo task run 'jupyter notebook' --port 8888
```

It sets up your project and files inside the environment to keep track of your progress.